# How to make my POCO classes appear in winforms DataSource list

Tags: c#, winforms

Let's say that I would like my binding list datasource to be typeof(Class1).

In the properties editor, I can't see my Class1 in the datasource list.

Is there any attribute I can decorate my class with, that will let my Class1 appear in the list ?  Something equivalent to the [DataObject] attribute in asp.Net project.

I don't want to create a project datasource for every class.  Actually, I replace the Control.DataSource assignation in the *.Designer.cs to be of typeof(Class1) to achieve it, but It would be nice if I could choose it directly from the properties editor.

Comment: I think it's the same.  Add a DataObject attribute to your class and you should be able to drill down to it from the DataBindings - Advanced property item, select "Add Project Data Source" from the Bindings dropdown, etc.

Comment: Adding to @LarsTech comment, you may need to have a successful build before you can add the class as a project data source.

Comment: @LarsTech Yes I can create a **Project Data Source** and don't even need the `[DataObject]` attribute. But the point is I don't like to pollute my project with all those xml files just to be able to generate a `DataSource = typeof(Class1)` in de Designer.cs.  I thought that maybe an attribute would have exist for that specific purpose. Thanx.

Comment: I personally try to avoid the designer as much as possible,  I usually connect my data sources in code, usually in the form's constructor.

Comment: @LarsTech Yes I know, but for this particular project I am using the forms resources to translate column labels etc. and it's easier to do it via the designer.  So I need the Design time binding to be able to do that